# Adding Jar file to java program using javac -cp is not working

Tags: java

I am trying to add jar file to java program using `javac -cp`, but it fails.I have a jar file which is called json-simple-2.1.2.jar and i have my java file called Testing.java. Both files are in this path `D:\eclipse-workspace\Test3\src`. Here is the code in `Testing.java`:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This how the import supposed to be i think.
and here is the command in CMD :

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\Test3\src>javac -cp json-simple-2.1.2.jar: Testing.java
```

This is the thrown error:

```
package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @StephenC note that it's Windows, so its `-cp json-simple-2.1.2.jar;.` . Different separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon (`:`) is for Unix-like OS-s, on Windows you need semicolon (`;`). But in fact for specifying a single "something" (path, jar, etc.), you do not need anything:

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\Test3\src>javac -cp json-simple-2.1.2.jar Testing.java
```

When running, you may need to specify the current path (`.`), and use the semicolon:

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\Test3\src>java -cp .;json-simple-2.1.2.jar Testing
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on Windows, so the path separator is a semicolon. This means that where you use : it should be a ;

```
javac -cp json-simple-2.1.2.jar; Testing.java
```